# How to confirm checkbox updated

Tags: website-design, checkboxes

How do you confirm that a change to a checkbox has been saved?

On our site when you want to change a textbox or drop-down, you click the pencil icon to change the value, click ENTER or TAB and that saves the new value. With a checkbox, you just click it and the new value is saved.

How do we confirm that checkbox change to the user?

Here are 2 screenshots showing the page before and during a user editing a textbox

[image: textbox being edited]

Comment: You don't need an extra interaction to confirm the change. The native check/uncheck would be enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can show confirmation popup on the top with message like "LTR order is ON" or something like that, but usually if there is no confirmation button user understand that all settings are automatically saved.

Answer (score 1):

You can show a small banner with a feedback message like "Your settings have been saved". This banner can auto-dismiss after 2-3 seconds. As an example, you can check out the banners that Gmail displays when a user deletes email or performs some other actions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a small tick mark that appears for some seconds after the user press enter to save the new value.

[image]